# Combination of all kinds of basic series stuffed together.

Tags: sequences-and-series

Till now, I have studied various types of series like AP,GP, A-GP and some other standard series too but this question came up as a pure combination of all these series.

The question said, Find:

$$ \sum _ {k=1}^{n}  {{(k^2)(4^k)} \over {(k+1)(k+2)}}$$

I could have easily performed the summation if they would have been given to me separately, but with each thing combined, I am not even able to start writing the solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We note that 
$$\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{\left(k^2 \right)\left(4^k \right)}{\left( k+1 \right)\left(k+2 \right)} = \sum_{k=1}^n 4^k \left( \frac{k^2}{k+1} - \frac{k^2}{k+2} \right) = \sum_{k=1}^n 4^k \left( k-1 + \frac{1}{k+1} - \left( k-2 + \frac{4}{k+2} \right) \right) = \sum_{k=1}^n 4^k \left( 1 + \frac{1}{k+1} - \frac{4}{k+2}  \right) = \sum_{k=1}^n 4^k + \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{4^k}{k+1} - \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{4^{k+1}}{k+2}.  $$
Do you now find it any easier?